# How to extract Source and Target tables from a Sql file using Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a sql file which contains insert select statements. I want to extract the table name in insert statement as a target table and table name in select statement as source table.

I tried with sql-metadata module which returns only the list of tables. Is there any way to extract the above mentioned items. Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from sql_metadata import Parser
from pathlib import Path
import re

root_dir = "C:\\Users\\user1\\File_Scan"


# for filename in glob.iglob(f"{root_dir}/**/**.*", recursive=True):
#         print(os.path.abspath(filename))



#Exclude Sub dirs
skip_dirs = ["Test3", "queries34"]
def excludeFolders(root_folder, exclude_list):
    all_files = glob.glob(f"{root_folder}/**/**.sql", recursive=True)
    multiple_paths = "|".join(exclude_list)
    filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: not re.search(multiple_paths, x), all_files))
    return filtered_list

filtered_items = excludeFolders(root_folder=root_dir, exclude_list=skip_dirs)
table_list = []

for file in filtered_items:

    f = open(file, "r")
    query = f.read()

    tables = Parser(query).tables
    f.close()

    table_list.append([(Path(file).name), file, (", ".join(tables))])

final_table_lst = pd.DataFrame(table_list, columns=["File_Name", "File_Path", "Associated_Tables"])
final_table_lst.sort_values("File_Name", inplace=True)
final_table_lst.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
final_table_lst.index += 1
final_table_lst.index.name = 'S.No'
final_table_lst.to_csv('C://Users//user1//sql_file_scan.csv')
print("Output is Written to CSV!")
```

Comment: You might want to have a llok at [this](https://github.com/Andromelus/sql-to-mermaid-awk). It is a program, in awk, that lists all tables and draws a diagram of dependencies. You may get inspired by it to achieve what you want.